# Error in tag badges

Tags: bug, status-completed

I'm seeing 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.String]' on the [badge list](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges):

> [image]

Comment: I've edited your post to remove the "my". That's the general badge list in the help center, it just includes check marks for the badges already owned by the visitor. Your badge list in your profile. That "my" is therefore a bit confusing.

Comment: This also happens on other SE sites, so posting this on SE is suitable as well.

Comment: @tom [posted already](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345882/system-threading-tasks-task1system-string-in-the-badge-list-page)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has been fixed. [As per m0sa♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/345884) (SE staff):

> This will be fixed shortly, we missed an `await` call in our .NET Core port.

`` System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.String] `` no longer appears.