# When banned from editing, an uninformative "StackHtmlContent" page appears when attempting to suggest edits

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits, edit-ban

Some time ago, for a few days, I wasn't able to edit any post. When I clicked on the edit option, this page is shown:

[image]

This page *probably* appears as a result of being banned from editing. It looks like a broken placeholder page.

[Another user](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/396264/when-i-click-on-the-edit-post-button-i-see-a-page-that-looks-like-a-coding-erro?noredirect=1#comment769248_396264) has run into the problem too, so it's not just on my side.

Can Stack Exchange fix it so that a more informative message is given instead? Maybe something like "You have had too many edit suggestions rejected recently, you may start proposing edits again on `<DATE>`."

Comment: What's the URL of that page? Something like /review/suggested-edits/123 or /posts/123/edit ? Open your browser console, see if any site resources are failing to load. Could also try disabling dark mode, see if that makes a difference

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61024617/edit  This is URL. Dark mode and light mode have not any difference here. @CertainPerformance

Comment: Banned from edit? Or there are too many edits pending approval (211 now - that's I think above the limit when more edits that need review are allowed).. Also I think in both cases there should be some notifcation... like missing "edit" button...

Comment: Also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351727/how-come-the-suggested-edits-queue-can-suddenly-become-so-big/351728#351728 claims edit queue limit is 500...

Comment: It isn't review queue. SO didn't send any notification about this. I don't know it's temporary and it will be fixed itself or I should do something.@Alexei Levenkov

Comment: We switched to running on .net core earlier this week, and it's entirely possible that there's a bug (on our end) in the view here. We'll investigate. Thanks for the report!

Comment: Your welcome @AdamLear, I send an email to SO yesterday and they said until today it will be solved. But it hasn't solved yet.

Comment: @AdamLear Possibly related: [Error in tag badges](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/396158/4642212).

Comment: @MohammadMoeinGolchin I can't reproduce this. Is the problem still happening? If so, mind taking a full page screenshot, please? Thanks!

Comment: @Adam Lear, no, problem solved yesterday and I can edit posts like previous.

Comment: @MohammadMoeinGolchin Cool, great to hear it :)

Comment: I have again this problem@AdamLear

Comment: @AdamLear probably didn’t get pinged because there is no space before the @.

Comment: Please help me to get rid of this issue @AdamLear

Comment: @MohammadMoeinGolchin That's... odd. No related changes on our end that I'm aware of. Can you take a full page screenshot for me, please, including the address bar? And are you running any user scripts?

Comment: The screen is blank, just that text in image are seen and of course general view of Stack Overflow. What do you mean user scripts? @AdamLear

Comment: @MohammadMoeinGolchin I mean things like browser plugins. The reason I'm asking for a screenshot is that I can't even find the view you're being served in our code, so I want to make sure I'm looking in the right place. Most importantly, I need the URL, but seeing the whole page would be helpful.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61220627/edit @AdamLear

Comment: @MohammadMoeinGolchin You [can also](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/396596/when-i-want-to-edit-this-page-is-shown-what-is-its-meaning?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment765557_396596) try viewing the page *with different machines/browsers/logins/IP addresses*, it could help narrow things down

Comment: It is the same for me with different IPs and I tried with Mozilla and Explorer, they had the same result@CertainPerformance

Comment: My problem isn't solved yet @AdamLear

Comment: My problem isn't solved yet @CertainPerformance

Comment: I can't reproduce this on the latest version of Firefox for Windows (or on Chrome, FWIW). Are you sure you're not using any user scripts or extensions? (That doesn't look like the default SO dark mode). Did you try [restarting Firefox with add-ons disabled](https://smallbusiness.chron.com/start-firefox-addons-59185.html)? If you could reproduce this on Firefox without extensions, that would be more credible.

Comment: How can I know I am using user scripts or not? @AhmedAbdelhameed

Comment: @MohammadMoeinGolchin Try disabling add-ons as I suggested above (visit the link to know how). Regarding your question, if you don't know what user scripts are, you probably don't have them. You _do_, however, have extensions and you might have ones that alter the DOM of the SO website. The way your screenshot looks like suggests that you probably do. Anyway, it doesn't matter. If you follow my suggestion and disable all add-ons, you should get a clean instance of Firefox. Let us know if you still get the same page after you do so.

Comment: I try that but again I get previous result. About user scripts please explain more. I got a warning at top of page several days ago, maybe it was about user script. What can I get rid of use user scripts? @AhmedAbdelhameed

Comment: Also I should say that I have this problem only for edit page, and in my Android phone when I open SO I haven't edit option at all. @AhmedAbdelhameed

Comment: Problem is from my account not my browser, please check it @AdamLear

Comment: @MohammadMoeinGolchin _“What can I get rid of use user scripts?”_ — There are two comments above pointing out how to disable extensions (aka add-ons). Please find them, read them, and follow the steps.

Comment: Problem is from my account as I said @user4642212

Comment: After I tried several times, I saw a message which said: edit queue is full. But again that page was shown. @CertainPerformance

Comment: @MohammadMoeinGolchin Does it happen on every post you try to edit?

Comment: Sometimes I see edit queue is full and sometimes I see page I have attached @AdamLear

Comment: My problem solved after about 10 days. It seems that I was banned from edit. But SO didn't show me any warning. Just this page was shown.

Comment: @AdamLear Check the question again, I think the cause has been identified. It seems quite likely that this bug results from trying to suggest an edit while being banned from editing. [tajniak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7082164/tajniak?tab=activity) is experiencing this bug as well.

Comment: Nick Craver pushed a set of changes that hopefully fixed this earlier today. If you have a moment, can you confirm, please? Thanks!

Comment: Hi, my issue is solved, how can I confirm it?

Comment: @AdamLear seems that Nick only allowed the user to know they are review banned, but not for how long https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/399714/792066