# Suggest edit: StackOverflow.StackHtmlContent

Tags: bug, edits, suggested-edits

I want to edit a post. When I click the "edit" button, it returns: StackOverflow.StackHtmlContent. I don't know why. Can any moderator give me a point?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When banned from editing, an uninformative "StackHtmlContent" page appears when attempting to suggest edits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/396264/when-banned-from-editing-an-uninformative-stackhtmlcontent-page-appears-when)

Comment: That one is marked "status-completed", although it would seem it's not really so.

Comment: @yivi Yes. It seems that I was banned from edit. SO didn't show me any warning. Maybe SO could send me an email or something.

Comment: No you are not banned from suggested edits.

Comment: @SamuelLiew If so, I do not know why it shows: StackOverflow.StackHtmlContent :)

Comment: thanks, this is definitely a bug; we're investigating

Comment: We're not 100% sure based on the description we fixed the right thing here but we're pretty sure - can you please confirm this is no longer happening?