# Error on Teams Use Case (for Engineering) Page

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-for-teams

Similar to [this issue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/396158/4039768).

On [Engineering Teams: Use Case Page](https://stackoverflow.com/teams/use-cases/engineering),
it's showing below code:

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.String]
```

[image: Check code below **email address** input]

Comment: This issue has been resolved by SO team.